# calling jpa persist on detached entity does not insert duplicate row. Why?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We have realized that some classes in our project make user of
em.persist(Book); to update existing book records.

first the book is retrieved

```
em.find(id);
```

then fields are modified through user input and then persisted

*em.persist(book);*

Although this worked fine without any problems till now it is making me curious since I expect JPA to insert a new Book with a different id when em.persist is called. I could not find any resource about persist method's behaviour when detached object ref. is passed.

thanks in advance

```
public void A() throws Exception{ // bean method

         try {

       oEntity=oServis.findById(kesintiLogEntity.getOrtaklikId()); //Transactional spring service method returns an existing record
         oEntity.setOrtakSureAy(ortakEntity.getOrtakSureAy()-1);//modify detached object
         oServis.saveOrtak(oEntity); //em.persist(oEntity);
} 
catch (Exception e){
}
}
```

Comment: Please add an example code, `persist` should throw a `EntityExistsException` for an existing entity being persisted.

Comment: can someone explain why my question is rated -1?

Comment: Perhaps because you did not append any minimal working example.

Comment: Now nobody can see what is oServis and oEntity. If an object is detached and then updated and then you call MERGE (not PERSIST) then it will be UPDATED, as per the JPA spec. No idea what you're doing.

Comment: i am assigned to an almost abandoned project (maintenance contract) , the existing code makes use of PERSIST to update existing records . I was scared first since there could be tons of duplicate records but there are none. I was trying to figure out how could that happen. If the detached entity was an id EntityManager issues an Update statement even detached entity is persisted but not merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine since your find method grabs an existing item with id field, if you want new object just create a new object and copy values from the object you find and then persist the newly created object

Edit:

Please look here is a nice diagram describing entity states
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed

Comment: Thanks for the responseI have added the mentioned code , we do not want a new object at all  , just trying to gain a deeper insight about persist()'s behaviour when detached entity retrieved from db is passed.