# Spring Boot JPA .save() updates all records

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, drools, rule-engine

I have an entity class Alert, when I create a new ALert and save it, it replaces all the rows with the matching parameters, Reading and Priority can be duplicate in Alert entity. Below is the code for Alert.class. What is the issue?

```
package com.github.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
public class Alert {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private int u_id;
    @Embedded
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Reading.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vin")
    private Reading reading;
    private String priority;
    private UUID uuid;

    public Reading getReading() {
        return reading;
    }

    public void setReading(Reading reading) {
        this.reading = reading;
    }


    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

}
```

I am saving alert like below:

```
Alert alert = new Alert();
alert.setUuid(uuid);
alert.setReading(reading);
if (alert.getPriority().equals("High") || alert.getPriority().equals("Low") || alert.getPriority().equals("Medium"))
alertRepository.save(alert);
```

Updated Details 1:

- First I insert a record in the alert table based on conditions. Then
  I insert again with a new ID generated automatically, but with the
  same alert parameters (readings, priority) except timestamp. when I
  save the alert object like above all the records are getting updated
  in the database.
- Timestamp is a field of readings
- vin is the Id for readings

Update 2: Is this anyway related to sessions? Ref. [calling jpa persist on detached entity does not insert duplicate row. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472106/calling-jpa-persist-on-detached-entity-does-not-insert-duplicate-row-why)

Update 3: I think it's because of the way I create alert entity. I am using drools, java rules and insert row. I had created the alert as global. I now changed this.

Below is my rule, where/how should I create the Alert entity in rules to persist:

```
rule "engine RPM"
    when
        alert: Alert()
        reading: Reading()
        vehicle: Vehicle(getVin() == reading.getVin(), getRedlineRpm() < reading.getEngineRpm())
    then

        new Alert().setPriority("High");

    end
```

Comment: @ Embedded and @ JoinColumn doesn't work together. These are two different methods. Remove @ Embedded : )

Comment: @EmilHotkowski Removed, same issue.

Comment: I don't understand your error, could you elaborate or provide an exmaple?

Comment: First I insert a record in the alert table based on conditions. Then I insert again with a new ID generated automatically, but with the same alert parameters (readings, priority) except timestamp. when I save the alert object like above all the records are getting updated in the database. Timestamp is a field of readings.

Comment: @EmilHotkowski Errm it is `@Embedded` and `@ManyToOne` that dont go together. `@JoinColumn` is bugger all to do with it. See any JPA mapping docs for that

Answer (score 0):

According to the [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association), while using @JoinColumn annotation:

> It has one more parameters named referencedColumnName. This parameter
>   declares the column in the targeted entity that will be used to the
>   join. Note that when using referencedColumnName to a non primary key
>   column, the associated class has to be Serializable.

Make sure your class serializable

Comment: for saving object set alert.setUuid(org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone(uuid)):

Comment: does it make any difference? the id I'm generating is already unique.

Comment: it will make difference when you get uuid from db and set directly to new object.